# Update Ionic UI element with callback

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, appery.io

**Stroy:**
I am doing small mobile application with appery.io which will scan qr code and according to value hide/show a button.

**Problem:**
button will  hide when i change the variable(name:hide)  boolean value:

```
$scope.QRscanner = function (_callback) {
     cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(
          function (result)
          {
              if(result.cancelled!=1){

                $scope.hide = false;
                $scope.scannedValue = result.text;
                _callback(false);
              }
              else
              {    _callback(true);
                  alert("Operation cancelled");

              }

          },
          function (error) {
              $scope.hide = true;
          },
          {
              preferFrontCamera : true, // iOS and Android
              showFlipCameraButton : true, // iOS and Android
              showTorchButton : false, // iOS and Android
              torchOn: false, // Android, launch with the torch switched on (if available)
              prompt : "Place a barcode inside the scan area", // Android
              resultDisplayDuration: 500, // Android, display scanned text for X ms. 0 suppresses it entirely, default 1500
              formats : "QR_CODE,PDF_417", // default: all but PDF_417 and RSS_EXPANDED
              orientation : "landscape", // Android only (portrait|landscape), default unset so it rotates with the device
              disableAnimations : true // iOS
          }
       );
}
```

This is the callback function;

```
$scope.Callback = function (result) 
{
alert("result"+result);
$scope.hide=result;
}
```

Finally i will call this QRscanner function in **ng-click** with parameter callback function name.

```
QRscanner(Callback);
```

I'm very new to ionic + angular.kind help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have the following two buttons:

```
<button ng-click="QRscanner()"> Scan Code </button>
<button ng-hide="hide"> Button to Hide </button>
```

if you have both buttons in the same controller Is not necessary to send the callback as a parameter, you just call the function:

```
$scope.hide = false;

function Callback(result) {
    alert("result" + result);
    $scope.hide = result;
}

$scope.QRscanner = function() {
    cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(
        function(result) {
            if (result.cancelled != 1) {

                $scope.hide = false;
                $scope.scannedValue = result.text;
                Callback(false);
            } else {
                Callback(true);
                alert("Operation cancelled");

            }

        },
        function(error) {
            $scope.hide = true;
        }, {
            preferFrontCamera: true, // iOS and Android
            showFlipCameraButton: true, // iOS and Android
            showTorchButton: false, // iOS and Android
            torchOn: false, // Android, launch with the torch switched on (if available)
            prompt: "Place a barcode inside the scan area", // Android
            resultDisplayDuration: 500, // Android, display scanned text for X ms. 0 suppresses it entirely, default 1500
            formats: "QR_CODE,PDF_417", // default: all but PDF_417 and RSS_EXPANDED
            orientation: "landscape", // Android only (portrait|landscape), default unset so it rotates with the device
            disableAnimations: true // iOS
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: thank for the reply;i have already fix this but bit different way.i had to call $scope.$apply();in call back to update the UI

Comment: You could add ngCordova/Ionic Native to your project, they has AngularJS wrappers, and make easier to use all native plugins. With ngCordova you wont need to do the apply() manually, because all services returns promises. You should take a look to them. http://ngcordova.com/docs/